# How to use review in our custom module?

Tags: magento

How to use review (pending review ,all review) in our custom module on back  end ?
Thanks so much for all your answers.

Answer (score 0):

To get a review summary of a product, you can do

```
$summary = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->load($productId);
if ($summary->getId()) {
    $rating = $summary->getRatingSummary();
}
```

Then `$rating` will have a number (out of 100) that is the rating summary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What I was trying to say was how to make a pending and approved system like the review module for my custom module with custom content.

Thanks again

Comment: You have to write your own custom module. Read more at http://alanstorm.com/category/magento